# Field Source doesn't appear in Import Contributions

Tags: contributions, import

I'm trying to import contributions. I found all the fields except the "Source" field.

Is there any reason for not appearing? Is there a way to show it?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contribution source field is available during import and export. Its labeled as 'Contribution Source'.

[image]

Comment: Oh! I was focused on finding the field with the same name. Perfect answer, thanks you.

Comment: Always Pleasure :)